# Unable to SSH but need to open ubuntu terminal to fix

Tags: 18.04, ssh, ufw

I was setting up my Apache server in Ubuntu 18.04 while checking the Firewall, I used some command like:

```
sudo ufw allow enable
```

... like that and didn't enable ssh, post which my SSH is not working.

Now I am not able to access the server through putty using port 22.

I need to run `sudo ufw allow ssh` to enable 22, but how do I enter this command while ssh is not working and don't have access to the terminal of my server?

Comment: If you don't have any remote access tools, you'll need physical access to the server to correct this issue.

Comment: if your Ubuntu server is in the cloud, see the cloud service provider documentation and help. If you have physical access, or you can call someone with physical access go there and fix the problem.

Comment: i reimaged my VM.